# .Net Core microservice and inspecting Cognito JWT claims for use in authorization

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing a .net service that I am passing a Cognito generated JWT in the client that has a group claim that I hope to use to restrict API access as the JWT is passed in as a Bearer token with each API call from the front-end. e.g.

> "cognito:groups":["Guest"]

In my code now I have added:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = false,
            RoleClaimType = "cognito:groups"
        };
    });
```

I have setup up my roles and my permissions using the [HeimGuard](https://github.com/pdevito3/HeimGuard) project. In testing as I change roles in the Bearer token none of my APIs that restrict access to Guest do not deny access when decorated with [Authorize]. So, nothing is restricted. Any thoughts or ideas you have in how to solve this problem helps immensly. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried custom AuthorizeAttribute as below:

To create the Token:

```
public class UserModel
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string PassWord { get; set; }

        public string Right { get; set; }
    }

[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Authenticate(UserModel someuser)
        {
            var claims = new Claim[]
            {
               new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
               new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, someuser.Role), 
               new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, someuser.Username), 
               new Claim("Right", someuser.Right) 
            };
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

           
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
              _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
              signingCredentials: credentials,
              expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2),
              claims: claims
            );

            string jwtToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            
            return Content(jwtToken);
        }
```

codes in appsettings.json:

```
"Jwt": {
    "Key": "ThisismySecretKey",
    "Issuer": "Test.com"
  }
```

Custom requirement:

```
public class WriteRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<WriteRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, WriteRequirement requirement)
        {
            var right = context.User.FindFirst("Right").Value;
            if(right=="Write")
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Fail();
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

       
    }
```

in startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            ...

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                    {
                        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            ValidateIssuer = false,
                            ValidateAudience = false,
                            ValidateLifetime = false,
                            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                            ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                        };
                    });
            services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, WriteRequirement>();
            services.AddAuthorization(opyions => { opyions.AddPolicy("Write", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new WriteRequirement())); });
            ...
        }
```

The Action need Authrization:

```
[HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]
        [Authorize(Policy="Write")]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5" };
        }
```

The Result:

[image]

Comment: Wow!! Thank you! This helped me so much. Can't thank you enough!